# How can I deploy an ASP.NET web on IIS without creating a separate site?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've created an ASP.NET web tool that will just be used by a few people in my team where I work.  I deployed it on our internal (Win2k, IIS6) web server by creating a new website in IIS and assigning it port 81.  Users can access it with an address like http://myserver:81.  All the other web stuff on the server is classic ASP and is accessed with addresses like http://myserver/path/to/myfile.asp.

This works fine, but I'd rather set it up so that the ASP.NET app is not configured as a separate web site, and is just accessed via a folder path like the classic asp stuff.  That way users wouldn't have to specify the port and we wouldn't get the overhead of an additional web site for every little ASP.NET app we make.

The problem is when I build the site in visual studio, it compiles all the .cs files into one .dll file, and if I just copy everything over to some folder on the server and type the address of the .aspx file, it can't seem to access any of the c# functions in that .dll file.

Can an ASP.NET app be set up like this, short of writing all C# code within the .aspx files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming you want your application to run as a subfolder of a website bound to http://192.168.1.1:**

1. Build your website, and drop it into a subfolder called "A" in the root website folder
2. Verify that `Network Service` and `IUsr` accounts have read access (at least) to your Subfolder
3. Verify that the application pool serving the website is using the same version of the .NET Framework as your application (Probably 2.0 if you're using IIS 6)
4. Verify that the application pool is running under the Network Service Identity
5. Right click the folder in IIS, and convert it to an application
6. Make sure you setup an adequate default file on the application, such as default.aspx
7. Access http://192.168.1.1/A/ and your application should load

**Note:** All applications in the website must run the same version of the .NET Framework

Comment: Note: I recommend using a different website. There really is no overhead if you make it use the same application pool as another website.

Comment: When I right click a folder in IIS6 there is no option to convert to application (think this option was added in IIS7).  I can right click>properties and in the application section click create.  This changes the icon to an application icon, but still doesn't work.

Comment: You did the correct thing (converting it to an application).  What happens when you visit the application?

Comment: When I go to http://myserver/myapp it just shows the folder contents.  My app and the server are on .NET 2.0.  There is a default.aspx file, but I'm not sure how to set that to default in the application settings.  The 'Everyone' group has read access to this folder.  I'm not sure how to check what identity the application pool is running under.

Comment: Make sure IUsr and Network Service both have read access. Also, what file do you want to be processed when a user visits the folder? If the file is named "Test.aspx". Here's how to set the default document for a website: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true    Furthermore, make sure that you have installed the proper version of ASP.NET http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/7ecaa5f3-5499-4887-8c9d-00aba71125df.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: More info on installing the correct version of ASP.NET  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Ok the default document was set to default.asp, so I changed that to default.aspx.  Now when I go to the site it does attempt to load it, but I am getting a lot of errors (missing folders and such) related to web.config.  The errors are from the root web.config of the default web site, not the web.config from my app, even though in the properties of my app in asp.net settings it is set to use the web.config of my app.  Is there a way to make it ignore the default web.config?